# Compare two files in makefile

Tags: makefile, compare

I need help with comparing two files in makefile.
I need something like this:

```
if [cmp $(FILE1) $(FILE2)] !=0; than 
 echo "OK" 
else 
 echo "WRONG" 
fi
```

But I am not sure how exactly to do that,
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit: corrected mistaken use of `-z` to `-eq 0` and added Makefile context help.**

It's really a shell question, not specific to makefiles, but this code would work:

```
cmp -s $(FILE1) $(FILE2)
RETVAL=$?
if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "SAME" 
else 
    echo "NOT SAME" 
fi
```

In a makefile rule, that would look like:

```
my_compare:
    cmp -s $(FILE1) $(FILE2); \
    RETVAL=$$?; \
    if [ $$RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then \
            echo "SAME"; \
    else \
            echo "NOT SAME"; \
    fi
```

Comment: I know it would be better in shell but I must do it in makefile. Your code compare files but then on RETVAL there is Error 1.

Comment: You can do it in a makefile, sure - maybe your question was how to get the shell actions to execute correctly in a makefile rule - that wasn't so clear from the question. If so, see edit.  Also note that I corrected the shell code - it had a mistake - oops, sorry.

Comment: I am sorry if I didn´t say it clear but I needed it in a makefile rule. Now it works, thank you

Comment: @Bibo - it was pretty clear actually - my bad :)  glad it helped.

Comment: Why don't you test `$?` (i.e., `$$?`) directly? I see no reason to store it in `RETVAL`.

Better yet, just execute `cmp` in the `if`: `if cmp -s $(FILE1) $(FILE2); then ...`

Comment: @Jack - I agree with putting the `cmp` in the `if` itself - good point.  But I have learned from experience to always save the exit status of shell commands in something named `RETVAL` since it avoids those tricky bugs when the next programmer comes along and puts other commands between, not realizing that the `if` was inextricably linked to the last command that was run.  Putting it immediately in a variable makes this more obvious (I think) and makes it more maintainable.

Comment: @e.dan re `RETVAL`: I guess that makes sense, but I'd store `RETVAL` on the same line as the command whose `$?` you are capturing.

Answer (score 3):

Return code from `diff` command will be 0 if files are identical, and 1 if files differs.